# Google Cloud Storage transactions?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

It does not appear that GCS has any transaction mechanism. Is this correct?

I would like to be able to have a long lived transaction. For example, it would be great if I could start a transaction and specify an expiration time (if not committed within X time it automatically gets rolled back). Then I could use this handle to insert objects, compose, delete etc. and if all goes well, issue a isCommitPossible(), and if yes, then commit().

Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Object writes are transactional (either the complete object and its metadata are successfully written and the object becomes visible; or it fails without becoming visible). But there's no transaction mechanism spanning multiple GCS operations.

Comment: Any chance that this will be added in the future?

Comment: @RobertD: We have no current plans to support transactions spanning multiple requests. However, we're always interested in real world use cases, so if you're willing/able to share some details about why you want this support I'll share it with our product management. You can send to gs-team@google.com if you'd prefer not to post that information publicly.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz I have a use-case: I'd like multiple clients to be able to concurrently *append* information to a single gcs file. Unless I'm mistaken, this would require a read, and then a write, the pair of which would need to be atomic so as not to possibly overwrite a different client's modification. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @Hans Brende: GCS doesn't support appending to an object, other than just continuing to write to an object that has not yet been finalized; and for that case, the already-written bytes are immutable, so it's not possible to overwrite bytes written by another client. Could you instead have the multiple clients each write to a different object?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz the absence of "append" functionality is exactly the reason why I'd need an atomic *read* and write: A read to read the existing file and append the new data, and a write to overwrite the existing file with the longer version. I could have the different clients write to different files, but then I'd have to keep a separate file where each client would have to append the filename of the file they wrote to, which brings us back to the original problem!

Comment: @Hans Brende: It sounds like you want to do concurrency-safe read-modify-write updates. If that's what you want to do, you can use object preconditions - please see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_Preconditions

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Storage client libraries offer a file-like object to work with, which has an Open() and Close() operation. If a single operation can be transactional then, in theory, it should be possible to open a single "lock file" for the duration of all other operations, only closing it when you're done will all the other files.

In other words, you would have to write your processes to use a "lock file" and, in that way, you could, at the least, know whether or not all your files were written/read or if there was some error. Whenever the next round of operations takes place, it would just look for the existence of the lock file that corresponds to the set of files written (you'd have to arrange your naming, directory layout, etc, to have it make sense for this). If it exists, we can assume that the file group was written successfully. If it doesn't exist, assume that something happened (or that the process hasn't yet completed).

I have not actually tested this out. But I offer it as an idea for others who might be desperate enough to try.

Comment: Yep, that could work but it is a lot of work for something that could be automatic. The concept of a long running transaction spanning multiple stateless calls is something that is missing from most cloud APIs... Ideally you could open a transaction on a storage engine like Google Cloud Storage like this  String txnId = gcs.startTransaction(60) and get back a txnId (a string that is a unique transaction identifier) that can live across multiple stateless calls.... request 1 gcs.writeSomething(txnId, other params) finally gcs.commit(txnId) or gcs.rollback(txnId).

Comment: ... and  If the transaction isn't committed within the specified time frame (60 seconds in this example) it would automatically roll back. You could have it be very long for complex orcharstrations (5 or 10 minutes or even longer) and reasonally short for most things (5 or 30 seconds). And you could check txn status easily gcs.status(txnId) could return a JSON object with things like when txn started, current status, flag for canCommit:true/false to enable use with 2 phase commit, etc. Too bad nobody appears to be thinking about this.