# What is the correct cloud equivalent of saving a file in the database with a transaction?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, azure-storage

A question about AWS S3 storage but I believe this applies to Azure storage or any other sort of data store, too.

How do you deal with storage "transactions" in the cloud?

If you save your files, in the database, things are super easy:

- User does an API call where he gives his name and a photo
- You create a DB transaction
- Create a new user in the User table
- Upload the photo to the Document table
- Other events fire, but one of them goes wrong.
- Transaction rollback, show error to the user, done! No documents are uploaded

Same goes for deleting:

- User wants to delete photo
- Delete photo from database
- Other events happen, one of them go wrong
- rollback, nothing has happened to the photo, show error.

---

Now, doing this in the cloud seems impossible?? I believe S3 does not support transactions (nor Azure blob storage i believe), so what if you wanna delete the document? With a transaction it would not have been "saved" in the s3 storage yet until we say "GO! ".
You can't easily DELETE it now, the error occurred somewhere else in the application

Same goes for DELETING failures. What if you delete it from AWS but another event fails so you wanna rollback? In this case I guess you can undelete it thanks to soft deletes, but how? where??

The things that the engineers have come up with are all complex or "slow":

- Create a DocumentLog table (id, document data, filename, generated_guid_for_cloud_id, DesiredState (ADD/DELETE), succeeded (TRUE/FALSE)) and save the document in there.
  Insert it in there and start a job after the request.

  - The job checks that DocumentLogtable and either uploads the document or deletes it, according to the desiredstate.
  - Afterwards you still wanna update that row in the table, because it now succeeded. Or perhaps you wanna delete your row entirely.

    - *but what if that update in the database fails?*
- Send a "UploadDocumentCommand" on a queue somewhere and upload it AFTER the request succeeded. But this is a web app, it would be odd to show a placeholder image to the user if the upload to aws is slow/broken because the request just succeeded according to the user.
- Just forget about this problem. Run a cleanup job every X amount of time and look for files in the storage system that have no references in the database any more and delete them.

  - What if you have lots of files? this would get super expensive and slow, very quick! If you decide to only retrieve the last X time worth of files to save on time and money, What if your cleanup job was down for some time and now a file slips through? This will not ever be caught..

I'd love to hear your thoughts!

These are very complicated and require lots of code. What is the best way to do these things?

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job! If you want a transaction, use a transactional system, MySQL or Postgres are great for that. If you use decentralized and highly scalable component, you won't be able to do it, easily. it's not a matter of cloud or not, it's a question of choice and tool. You have tradeoff in each of your choices! You won't hit a nail with a screwdriver, you can, but it's difficult and dangerous. Here it's the same!!

Comment: As this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23436244/google-cloud-storage-transactions) mentions, for Google Cloud Storage  there's no transaction mechanism spanning multiple GCS operations.